# ESP-01 and HC-SR04 problems booting up

Tags: esp8266, pins, hc-sr04, espressif

I have a problem in a project that I am working, basically I need to use a ESP-01 to receive the measurements from a HC-SR04 and send it to another ESP-01 (which I won't cover here).

Basically my ESP doesn't boot 95% of times, it just stays with the blue LED on all the time, on the remaining 5% of cases it boots normally and reads the sensor and also sends the information to another ESP.

I have done a lot of research and I am aware of these points:

1. HC-SR04 works in 5V and ESP in 3.3v, so a level convertor would be needed for the GPIO pins.  But, I have seen that the manufacturer (Espressif) stated that the ESP is resistant to 5V logic and it should work.  Also, I asked my professor and he said that it wouldn't be a problem.
2. Both IO pins need to be HIGH to boot, and the sensor seems to supply low, but like I said the ESP01 does boot, but not all the times.

That said, I would like to know why it works sometimes and others not, trying to get a little more of stability for presentation purposes...

Also it's worth noting that I have another ESP-01 connected with a DHT11 sensor with basically the same settings and it works normally.

The connections go like this:

| ESP-01 | HC-SR04 |
| --- | --- |
| GPIO0 | Trigger |
| GPIO2 | Echo |
| GND | GND |

| Component | Power |
| --- | --- |
| ESP-01 Vcc, CH_PD | 3.3v |
| HC-SR04 Vcc | 5v |

The code:

```
// pins of the esp8266 connected to the sensor
#define trigPin 0  //GPIO0
#define echoPin 2  //GPIO2

// intialize the variables for storing the measurement
float timeElapsed;
float distance;
 
void setup() {
  // Init Serial Monitor
  Serial.begin(115200);

  pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT); // Sets the trigPin as an Output
  pinMode(echoPin, INPUT); // Sets the echoPin as an Input

}
 
void loop() {
  // do the measurements of the sensor
   digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);  //para generar un pulso limpio ponemos a LOW 4us
   delayMicroseconds(4);
   
   digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);  //generamos Trigger (disparo) de 10us
   delayMicroseconds(10);
   digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
   
   timeElapsed = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);
   distance = timeElapsed/58.3;

   delay(1000);
    
  if ((millis() - lastTime) > timerDelay) {
     // code to send the information over wi-fi

  }
}
```

I have tried already:

- Changing the ESP and HCSR04
- Inverting GPIO0 and GPIO2
- Boot without the sensor and connect it after, no succes
- Different values in Arduino IDE during compilation of code

Thanks for your attention!

Comment: You powered the SR04 with 3.3 Volt. That does not work reliably. https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=124216. The ultrasonic sender need more voltage to work well.

Comment: You should power up the HC-SR04 sensor with 5V, not 3.3V, as the sensor do not work properly with 3.3v supply

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, the HCSR04 is powered by 5V, i just typed incorrectly.